# How to use conditions referring to several colums in order to fill a third column in Python

Tags: python

I would like to fill my "Verif" column with values depending on several conditions referring to several columns all in the same df.
If "Reception" is empty and "Premier" is 'entrant radio' then "Verif" becomes 'utilisateur' ;
If "Reception" is empty and "Premier" is different from 'entrant radio' then "Verif" becomes 'n° de renvoi' ;
Else (=when "Reception" is not empty) write 'MEVO' in "Verif "
However, the result in Verif is MEVO everywhere.

```
for a in ['Reception']:
  for b in ['Premier']:
    if a == "" and b == 'Entrant Radio':
      df['Vérif'] = "utilisateur"
    elif a == "" and b != 'Entrant renvoyé par le MSC':
      df['Vérif'] = "n° de renvoi"
    else:
      df['Vérif'] = "MEVO"
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: for a in `df['Reception']:` maybe?

Comment: Have you tried this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043086/conditional-fill-in-pandas-dataframe similar concept and might be able to parlay into what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RoadieRich just tried this... it returns "utilisateur" everywhere in my Verif column.

Comment: Also, you should correct this line: for b in df['Premier']:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to assign value to `'Vérif'` column based on the result return by a lambda or function (`get_verif` in below example). Inside the function, you can get the value of the row column using `row['<column name>']` and return different values that satisfy specific conditions

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Reception': ['not empty', '', '', ''], 'Premier': ['some string', 'Entrant Radio', 'Entrant renvoyé par le MSC', 'random string']})

def get_verif(row):
    if row['Reception'] == "" and row['Premier'] == 'Entrant Radio':
      return "utilisateur"
    elif row['Reception'] == "" and row['Premier'] != 'Entrant renvoyé par le MSC':
      return "n° de renvoi"
    else:
      return "MEVO"

df['Vérif'] = df.apply(get_verif, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may because of case sensitivity? "Entrant Radio" and "entrant radio" are not same values.

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
new_verif = []
for r, p in zip(df['Reception'], df['Premier']):
    if r == "":
        if p == 'entrant radio':
            new_verif.append('utilisateur')
        else:
            new_verif.append('n° de renvoi')
    else:
        new_verif.append('MEVO')

df['Verif'] = new_verif
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked, thanks @tax evader.
I used:

```
def get_verif(row):
  if row['Reception'] == "" and row['Premier'] == 'Entrant Radio':
    return "utilisateur"
  elif row['Reception'] == "" and row['Premier'] != 'Entrant Radio':
    return "n° de renvoi"
  else:
    return "MEVO"

Extraction_Entrant_Mobile['Vérif'] = Extraction_Entrant_Mobile.apply(get_verif, axis=1)
Extraction_Entrant_Mobile
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post "Thank you" as an answer. Accepting tax evader's answer was the right thing to do, but this answer does not add new information.